# Drupal Ajaxifying Everything

Tags: ajax, drupal

Is there any way of ajaxifying Drupal so that page reloads are not reloads but just content modifications?

So menus would be updated, content would be updated and any blocks etc. would be appropriately modified but without the overhead of spitting out the whole page to the the user for client-side fixing up and without losing the nice javascript UI that Drupal has (like collapsible fieldsets, draggable table items and other ajaxified modules etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the simplest solution is to use the ajax pagers in your views (this works only for one block at time or for the main content)
2. to ajaxify every form you can use http://drupal.org/project/ajax

if you want to ajaxify *everything* then a page reload is the better option to go =]

Comment: One thing to consider is that when you ajaxify a form, it automatically becomes a cached form, which will add to your cache_form database table. If you have a lot of visitors per day, this table will get very large (ours has gotten to be 30GB before). If you do this, make sure that you have a cron run deleting the expired entries. Also, disabling the form cache functionality causes the form not to submit, which is obviously not an option. Also, in response to your comment about ajaxifying everything, tell that to Facebook.